# How to extract Text in popover window using selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium

As am new to selenium. I need to find a way how I could get the text from the popup using selenium/ java so that I can compare the text with expected data.

Is there anyway I could extract the text from the popup.when I mouseover on WebElement **ACE** ,A popup appears and I have to extract datafrom it.Screenshot attached with html code.

Thanks in advance.

I tried following but no luck

WebElement lMail=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='ACE'][@class='footer-title twc-blue twc-roundbook']"));

```
        new Actions(driver).moveToElement(lMail).perform();


        Actions act = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement age_purpose = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'popover ng-scope ng-isolate-scope top fade in')]/div/div[@class='popover-inner']"));
        act.moveToElement(age_purpose).perform();
        String tooltiptextreal = age_purpose.getAttribute("innerHTML");[enter image description [enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Can you show us some html? In majority cases you don't need to use mouse over to make an element visible. In all cases where I was need to make to appear an element was by removing some class which have role to hide that element.

Comment: Look into `Driver.getWindowHandles();` or `driver.switchTo().alert()`

Comment: @BhavanKumar Relevant HTML please?